# Error -> "com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to" using Stream.filter

Tags: java, list, filter, java-stream

I have this exception when trying to get a sublist filter using Stream.filter:

```
 List<Presupuesto> PresupuestosTienda = presupuestos.stream().filter(item -> item.tienda.equals(LaTienda.nombre)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- Where 'presupuestos' is a `List<Presupuesto>` too.

My class Presupuesto is very simple:

```
public class Presupuesto {
String vendedor, tienda;
Date fecha;
double total;

public Presupuesto(){

}
public Presupuesto(String vendedor, String tienda, Date fecha, double total){
    this.vendedor=vendedor;
    this.tienda=tienda;
    this.fecha=fecha;
    this.total=total;
}
```

}

I don't really know why that happen. I took an example from internet and it works! there is not much difference.

https://github.com/rey5137/tutorials-1/blob/master/java-streams/src/test/java/com/baeldung/stream/filter/StreamFilterUnitTest.java

Somebody know what it could be happening? Thanks a lot

Comment: What type is the variable `presupuestos`?

Comment: Hi Nosrep, it is a List<Presupuesto> too.

Answer (score 0):

I found that as the origin of my List was an Json converted with gson, the real type of each element in the List was a LinkedTreeMap and not a Presupuesto class Type. So know my problem is other. Thanks